# Incorrect meta Tags being read by crawlers for my React App subroute

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, reactjs, react-helmet

The issue I'm facing is If i were to share the sub route of my app `https://www.myapp.com/subroute`(**subroute url**) on Facebook the preview of the link post shows the title, description, and image from my main `root route` **`https://myapp.com`**.

How can I have link previews use the data from `subroute` on social media when `subroutes` are shared instead of the `root route` data from the `index.html`.

I tried to add the following Meta properties using [`react Helmet`](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet) on a sub route of my app `https://www.myapp.com/subroute`(**subroute url**) without success:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="subroute" />
<meta property="og:description" content="subroute description" />
<meta property="og:image" content="https://myapp.com/images/subroute.jpeg" />
```

Comment: 1. The meta data must be returned directly by the server, when the URL is requested. You can not set OG meta tags client-side via JavaScript. 2. You need to have `og:url` pointing to the actual URL.

Comment: Any other solution without changing the static page to dynamic one?

Comment: The way I solved this was to to prerender a static html with the met tags for the subroute using something like react-snap.